# WebAPI and mvc4 An error has occurred Type '.Controllers.APICategoryController' does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i having this error as title mention , what causes this anyone?? heres my code
i just want to display the files from SQL Database but it does have error any help? thanks!

```
    namespace a.Models

public interface ICatRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Category> GetAll();
    Category Get(int id);
    Category Add(Category item);
    void Remove(int id);
    bool Update(Category item);
}
```

another repository

```
namespace a.Models

public class CatRepository : ICatRepository
{

    private istellarEntities db = new istellarEntities();

    public CatRepository()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Categories;
    }

    public Category Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Categories.Find(id);
    }

    public Category Add(Category category)
    {
        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return category;
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        db.Categories.Remove(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public bool Update(Category category)
    {
        db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

controller

```
namespace a.Controllers

public class APICategoryController : ApiController
{
   // static readonly ICatRepository repository = new CatRepository();

 private readonly ICatRepository repository;

 public APICategoryController(ICatRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        }
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
{
    return repository.GetAll();
}
```

Lastly my class file

```
namespace a.Models

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.IQuestions = new HashSet<IQuestion>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IQuestion> IQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know you are asking a specific question... but you really should consider the repository pattern. Here the best example I have ever seen. https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper

Answer (score 1):

You've got one of the more helpful error messages there - APICategoryController does not have a default constructor, ie: a parameterless constructor.

You either need to use some kind of Dependency Injector for your code to know how to instantiate a concrete class for ICatRepository, or provide a default constructor.

eg:

```
     //a default constructor instantiating a concrete type. Simple, but no good for testing etc.
     public APICategoryController()
     {
         ICatRepository repository = new ConcreteRepository;
         this.repository = repository;
     }
```

Comment: i have added but it appears theres another error The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

Comment: That's a separate question really. Might be to do with Lazy Loading though (recursive serialization across entity navigation properties)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add default constructor. you should add this to APICategoryController (this is default constructor)

```
  public APICategoryController()
  {
  }
```

Comment: i have added but it appears that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.